# Javascript: How to prevent audio playing on page load?

Tags: javascript, audio, howler.js

I am using `howler.js` to implement my audio. What I have is extremely simple but the problem is the audio plays on page load even though I didn't specify as such.
Here is what I have:

```
var hoverSound = new Howl({
  src: ['../audio/hover.mp3']
 });

function whatEver() {
    if (whatever) {
    hoverSound.play();
   }
 }
```

This is my first time doing this so I'm not sure if there's like a "stop" audio or something. The above code works as intended after initial page load but refreshing the page means the sound plays on every initial load. How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Comment: What is your `whatever` if-statement checking for?

Comment: Do you only want it to play for the first time? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: My `if` statement just checks for mouse events. What I want is to prevent this audio from playing on page load. I only want it to play when the condition is met.

Comment: What is condition for `whatever` ?

Comment: I think the underlying reason is because `whatever` activates on page load which is normal. In that case I think I'll just set a time out function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your variable `hoversound` I'm guessing you want play sound when element hovered (`mouseenter`) and stop when leave (`mouseleave`)

```js
var hoverSound = new Howl({
  src: ['https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/rave_digger.webm']
});

document.getElementById("player").addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  hoverSound.play();
  this.innerHTML = "Leave to Stop";
  this.className += "playing";
  console.log("Playing...");
});
document.getElementById("player").addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  hoverSound.stop();
  this.innerHTML = "Hover to Play";
  this.className = "";
  console.log("Stopped...");
});
```

```css
#player {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #dd5427;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.playing {
  background-color: #689e0f !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/dist/howler.min.js"></script>
<div id="player">Hover to Play</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies to store 'whatever' variable.